# Integral of squared Bessel function

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, bessel-functions

I have been trying to find the solution to the integral

\begin{equation}
\int J_0^2(x) dx
\end{equation}
I tried a lot of stuff with known formulas for integrals of Bessel functions (see Abramowitz & Stegun (1972)) but haven't been successful...

Comment: I took a look at Luke's *Integrals of Bessel Functions* and it seems there is no nice formula for such an integral. You may integrate http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.8.E3 to obtain a series expansion for the primitive. The nice cases are those that involve certain powers of $x$ next to the Bessel function in the integrand, e.g., $\int x J_0^2(x) dx$ has a nice closed form.

Comment: It seems to just be a 4 argument Hypergeometric function.

Answer (score 1):

The answer can easily be given in Wolfram Alpha, but that would feel almost like cheating. Instead, let’s use  @Gary’s link on [DLMF 1.8.3 or 16.12.1](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.8.E3)
and the [**Generalized Hypergeometric function $\,_2F_3$**](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F3/). Note how the bottom of the DLMF page gives a hypergeometric representation comment. In theory, integration of a hypergeometric function is mainly another hypergeometric function:

$$\int J_0^2(x)dx=\int\,_0F_1(a,x)^2dx=\int\,_0F_1^2\left(1,-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)dx=\int\,_2F_3\left(1,\frac12,1,1,1,-x^2\right)dx=x\,_2F_3\left(\frac12,\frac12,1,1,\frac32,-x^2\right)+C$$

Note there are many alternate form for the answer like series and related functions. Try to simplify the solution if you like using the bolded link, but I have found nothing that has simplified for now. Please also see this [Antiderivative of the $\,_2F_3$](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F3/21/01/01/) function used here. Unfortunately, the area under the entire integrand, over the reals, is infinite. The takeaway is to put the function into hypergeometric form and integrate. Also note that there may be a typo. Please correct me and give me feedback

Comment: Thanks. I had indeed found the hypergeometric representation on Wolfram Alpha and Maple. I was hoping to find a solution in terms of other Bessel functions. For some other integrals involving Bessel functions I found solutions in terms of Bessel functions whereas both WA and Maple would only give the hypergeometric representations for those cases too. Therefore I wondered wether a solution in terms of Bessel functions was possible for this one too, but I haven't found any yet.

Comment: @Michaël Try playing around with [this link](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F3/) and [this link](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16) to try and simplify the hypergeometric function. The “specialized values” in Wolfram Mathworld do not apply here and I can’t seem to get Wolfram Alpha to recognize this hypergeometric function because it says “does not know how to interpret input”.

Comment: Also try using the sum representation of the hypergeometric function and find a different closed form of it. There are many possible [special functions](http://specialfunctionswiki.org/index.php/Category:SpecialFunction), besided Bessel functions.