# Integral of squared absolute of Bessel function of first kind

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, complex-integration, bessel-functions

As shown in the post on [Integral of squared Bessel function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4244360/69781) the integral of the squared Bessel function can be solved yielding a function including the gamma function $\Gamma$ and the generalized hypergeometric function$\,
   _2F_3$:$$\int J_n(x)^2 \,dx = \int J_n(x) J_n(x)  \,dz = \frac{2^{-2 n-1} x^{2 n+1} \,
   _2F_3\left(n+\frac{1}{2},n+\frac{1}{2};n+1,n+\frac{3}{2},2
   n+1;-x^2\right)}{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma (n+1)^2}$$ I'm interested if the absolute squared Bessel function $$\int |J_n(z)|^2 \,dz = \int J_n(z) J_n(z)^\ast \,dz, z\in\mathbb{C}$$can be solved as well. I would especially need a solution for the definite integral $$\int_{z_1}^{z_2} |J_0(z)|^2 \,dz$$